# Modernizr .no-js flicker on page load

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

On my wordpress website, i have a plugin (loftloader) that adds a preloader to my pages. It has a `div` that covers the whole page with a background, to hide the content when loading, just basic preloader behaviour.

Now, i noticed that when disabling javascript, it breaks the site, because the div never hides (as it cannot detect the loading is completed).

I added Modernizr and this bit of CSS, to hide the preloader for no-js browsers.

```
.no-js #loftloader-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

But it's creating a small bug : we get a glimpse of the loading page before the preloader appears.

**How can I fix this behaviour ?** I assume this is because Modernizr adds the no-js class by default then removes it ? (maybe i'm wrong)

Comment: Modernizer does not add the `no-js` because modernizer can only run if js is active. It remove the `no-js` class as soon as modernizer is loaded. Because of that it is important where and how you load modernizer. So where/how do you load modernizer?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant ! 
I load it right after the `<head>` opening tag and from cdnjs.com

Comment: Please show the whole `script` tag you use to load it.

Comment: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>`

Comment: That does not make sense, if you place this `script` tag in the `head` and you don't have `async` or `defer` as attribute, then rendering of the content should block until that script is loaded and executed. And you should not see a flickering. Do you have any css transition on that element, so it is a fade in  and out and not a flickering? Could you move the `script` tag at the beginning of the `head` so that it is the first element, and test if you still see that effect.

Comment: I know right! There is a transition but it seems to work only after the page has loaded. There's no fade transition when the "flicker" happens.
It is already the first tag after `head` !
You can see the demo here : https://lesdeuxvagues.com/demo/ (i know i should do a codepen but since i'm using plugins I don't really know how)

Comment: I doubt that the reason is modernizer and the `no-js` class. I think it is more a rendering problem that happens later. Maybe the `translation` properties that might result into a rendering glitch. But solving that problem is out of the scope of SO.

Comment: No it does come from Modernizr because, when i remove the `.no-js #loftloader-wrapper{ display: none; }` the problem disappears !

Comment: I don't say that this might not reveal a problem with the rendering engine of the browser. I just wanted to say that the initial reason might not be Modernzier, but some other part of the css code.  Even throtteling the network connection, here does not show the effect in FF, Chrome or Safari.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150851/discussion-between-marine-le-borgne-and-t-niese).